# Adding class to div when inside viewport

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a div element get an additional class added to it when it's inside the viewport. To achieve this I'm using a minified JQuery 1.11.0.

This is my JQuery code:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.textbox').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
        }
    });

});
```

I'm sure my class is visible but it's not adding the `visible` class for some reason. Any ideas why?
The CSS of my two affected classes are as follows:

```
.textbox {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    top: -10px;
    position: relative;
}
.textbox .visible {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to play a transition when it becomes visible. Fade in and drop down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's working. you just need to set `.textbox.visible` in css without spaces between the classes. they are 2 classes of the same element, so no space between them. see snippet below

or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yfv8jg2/4/)

( red div is you visible div )

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.textbox').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.textbox {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
  background:red;
  height:300px;
}
.textbox.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
}
.anotherdiv {
 width:100%;
 background:blue;
 height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anotherdiv">

</div>
<div class="textbox">

</div>
```

Comment: That solved it. It's weird though, on my menu that changes when scrolling 100 pixels adds a class aswell (not really the same jquery functions though) and it works fine with just a `.small` class in css. Maybe there's a logical explanation for it that I can't see. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: if you use just `.visible` it will also work. for example if your menu has class `.nav` and you write `.nav .small` it won't work. Either you write with no space `.nav.small` either just `.small` . but it's indicated that you write the longer version so you don't mess up your code if you have other elements with that class

Answer (score 0):

issue is in the inequalities, they should be stated like this:

elemTop <= docViewTop &
docViewBottom <= elemBottom

elemBottom should be greater than docViewBottom (since the latter has to be closer to the top) and elemTop bellow docViewTop (since we need docViewTop to be bellow elemTop, the former will be further away from top, so the value will be greater).

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. Did you accidentally hit "submit" early?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I corrected the issue.